# Validación en laravel

Tags: laravel-8

Tengo un campo que no es requerido, pero le pongo validaciones por si se introduce algo en ese campo:
'letra' => 'alpha|max:1'
Pero si no se introduce nada, también me realiza la validación y me lanza un error de que falta la letra. Hay alguna manera de poner que sea opcional.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Ya resuelto... el campo en la migración de la tabla, lo puse nullable(true)
y en la validación  'letra' => 'nullable|alpha|max:1' .
Ahora ya no me lanza el error. Y si escribo un numero en vez de una letra, ya me lanza error, de que tiene que ser una letra.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).